# Counting strings in positional arguments python (order cost calculator problem)

Tags: python

The goal is to calculate the cost of an order at a pizza shop. For example:

`cost([ ], ["pepperoni"], ["ham", "anchovy"], drinks = ["small"])`

should calculate the price of one plain pizza, one pizza with pepperoni toppings, one pizza with ham and anchovy toppings, and one drink (4 pizzas, one drink in total). The pizzas are arbitrary positional arguments but the drinks are named orders (keyword arguments). I was able to figure out how to count the number of positional arguments (pizzas) but I cannot figure out how to account for the price of the toppings.

I am confused about how to deal with positional arguments in this case: pizza. I am mainly confused about how to account for the toppings. I thought *pizza would allow me to access cost(pizza) as a list, but it does not work.

```
def cost(*pizza, drinks):

    for your_drinks in drinks:
        drinks_cost = drinks.count("small") * 2

    pizza_cost = len(pizza) * 13

    # this for loop does not behave the way I want it to.

    for toppings in pizza:
        toppings = pizza.count("pepperoni") * 1
                 + pizza.count("anchovy") * 2
                 + pizza.count("ham") * 1.5

    total = drinks_cost + toppings + pizza cost

    return total
```

Comment: Please repeat the intro tour, especially [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop doesn't quite display the logic you're looking for. In the first place your problem is that `list.count` isn't as smart as you want it to be:

```py
some_lst = [['a'], ['a', 'b'], ['b'], ['c']]

assert some_lst.count('a') == 0  # not 2??
assert some_lst.count('b') == 0  # not 2??
assert some_lst.count('c') == 0  # not 1??

assert some_lst.count(['a']) == 1  # Ahh now we see....
```

So instead you need to price each pizza separately. That seems doable. Create a new function and call it from `cost`:

```py
def cost_of_pizza(toppings):
    """Returns the price of a single pizza, as described as a list of toppings."""

    prices = {"pepperoni": 1,
        "anchovy": 2,
        "ham": 1.5}

    total = 0
    for topping in toppings:
        total += prices[topping]

    return total


def cost(*pizzas, drinks):

    # Some stuff goes here

    pizza_cost = 0
    for pizza in pizzas:
        pizza_cost += cost_of_pizza(pizza)

    # more stuff goes there
```

Note that both the `for topping in toppings: total += princes[topping]` and `for pizza in pizzas: pizza_cost += cost_of_pizza(pizza)` could be simplified by using a generator expression and the `sum` built-in.

```py
# toppings:
total = sum(prices[topping] for topping in toppings)

...

# pizzas:
pizza_cost = sum(cost_of_pizza(pizza) for pizza in pizzas)
```

---

However it's worth pointing out that you should strongly consider making a `Pizza` class whose instances know their own price.

```py
class Pizza(object):

    TOPPING_PRICES = {
        "pepperoni": 1,
        "anchovy": 2,
        "ham": 1.5
    }

    def __init__(self, *toppings):
        self.toppings = toppings

    @property
    def price(self):
        return sum(self.TOPPING_PRICES[topping] for topping in self.toppings)


# now let's use function annotations to do some typing,
# and I'll assume you've made a Drink class analogous to the one above...

from typing import List

def cost(pizzas: List[Pizza], drinks: List[Drink]):
    return sum(pizza.price for pizza in pizzas) + sum(drink.price for drink in drinks)
```

Comment: I ran the code and got a ```TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'```. It happens on two lines ```pizza_cost += cost_of_pizza(pizza)``` and ```total += prices[topping]```. I think it is because ```cost(*pizza, drink)``` which makes pizza a list. However, I cannot get rid of the asterisk because, without it, I will get an error ```TypeError: cost() got multiple values for argument 'drinks'```. How can I fix this?

Comment: @Julia612 "unhashable type" errors usually mean you're trying to look something up in a dictionary that can't be a key in a dictionary. Can you see what `topping` is? The code I gave you assumes you've given cost a list of list of strings for `pizza`, but that appears to not be the case?